# PHP returning null values when the data exists

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am running a making a mobile app that uses PHP to retrieve data from a web server.

When I run the SQL statement in the sql query it returns the correct data.

when I run the PHP it returns null values for the item at location 0 in the gameArray, all other items in the array show the right values

the code is as follows

```
$userResponse = array(
            'login' => $userName,
            'nickname' => $userNickName); 

$stmt = $conn->gamedb->prepare("SELECT player1, player2, currentturn, question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9 FROM Game WHERE Player1 = ? OR Player2 = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $userName, $userName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->store_result();

//create games array to be filled when stepping through the games
$gameResponse = array();

if($conn->gamedb->affected_rows > 0)
{
    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        $stmt->bind_result($player1, $player2, $currentTurn,
                           $question1, $question2, $question3,
                           $question4, $question5, $question6,
                           $question7, $question8, $question9);

        $gameArray = array($player1, $player2, $currentTurn,
                           $question1, $question2, $question3,
                           $question4, $question5, $question6,
                           $question7, $question8, $question9);


        //stores the game data into an array
        $gameResponse[] = $gameArray;
    }

    //close stmt
    $stmt->close();
}

$response = array(
            $userResponse,
            $gameResponse
            );

echo json_encode($response);
```

any help would be awesome!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with checking `affected_rows`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the manual page for [`mysqli_stmt::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), it clearly states

> Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling **mysqli_stmt_fetch()**.

Try this instead...

```
$gameResponse = array();

$stmt->bind_result($player1, $player2, $currentTurn,
                   $question1, $question2, $question3,
                   $question4, $question5, $question6,
                   $question7, $question8, $question9);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $gameResponse[] = array($player1, $player2, $currentTurn,
                            $question1, $question2, $question3,
                            $question4, $question5, $question6,
                            $question7, $question8, $question9);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could I suggest you try something a bit simpler?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $gameResponse[] = $row;
}
```

This way you don't have to go through all the gyrations of assigning variables and such. PHP will do that for you.